# Can't load an NSMutableArray with UIView objects

Tags: xcode, nsmutablearray

On my game board (which is called GameViewController), I have six Seats (in the xib) which are nothing more than subclassed UIViews (so I also have Seat.h and .m files in my project). When the game board gets initialized these seats also get created (thanks to the xib). I want to have the seats loaded into an NSMutableArray so that I can use them later. For some reason I can't get it to work.

In my GameViewController header file I've added NSMutableArray *seats; as an instance variable and included @class Seat; above the interface declaration.

In my awakeFromNib method of the GameViewController I have seats = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:6] retain]; So the array should be initialized when the game board appears.

Then in my Seat header file I've included GameViewController *controller; as an instance variable and included @class GameViewController above the interface declaration. I've also added and synthesized a property for the GameViewController.

In the Seat's awakeFromNib method I have [controller registerSeat:self];

This calls a method in my GameViewController that has only one line: [seats addObject:seat]; This should add the seat to the array. But for some reason this method never seems to get called. Or if it does, I can never tell. When I debug, focus never goes to the registerSeat method even though the seats do get added to the board. I hope this all makes sense. If the code is needed, I can provide it. It might be easier to do that anyway. What do you guys think? I'm stumped at the moment.

The method declaration is as follows:
- (void) registerSeat:(Seat *)seat;

GameViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class Seat;

@interface GameViewController : UIViewController {

  NSMutableArray *seats;

}

- (void) registerSeat:(Seat *)seat;

@end
```

GameViewController.m

```
#import "GameViewController.h"
#import "Seat.h"

@implementation GameViewController

- (void)awakeFromNib {

 seats = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:6] retain];

}

- (void) registerSeat:(Seat *)seat {

  [seats addObject:seat];
  NSLog(@"seat has been registered");

}

@end
```

Seat.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class GameViewController;

@interface Seat : UIView {

  GameViewController *controller;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet GameViewController *controller;

@end
```

Seat.m:

```
#import "Seat.h"
#import "GameViewController.h"

@implementation Seat

@synthesize controller;

- (void) awakeFromNib {

  [controller registerSeat:self];

}

@end
```

Comment: "But for some reason this method never seems to get called. Or if it does, I can never tell."  Try setting a breakpoint at the `[controller registerSeat:self]` method call, and see if it stops there.  Then step through to see where it goes from there.

Comment: I have done that and it does in fact stop there.  However, when I step through it then seems to dig deep into the framework.  An area where I'm completely unfamiliar with.  I have to click the step into button a ton of times and it just continues down this list of what looks like memory addresses and I cant get to the end of the list.  Wait, actually, when it stops on that line and I hit Step Into the focus actually moves past that line down to the } at which point when I click the Step Into button it then starts down that list.  So maybe it's not calling that function and just skipping it.

Comment: Okay, try putting another breakpoint on the first line of your `registerSeat` method.  See if that's getting hit.  In fact, you should be able to click Step Over at the first breakpoint and it should still stop in the `registerSeat` method if it is indeed getting called.

Comment: Okay, I added the second breakpoint on the first line of my registerSeat method and it's not calling it when I click the Step Over button at the first one.  It's been suggested to me that my seat objects have a controller property, but there's nothing that sets up that controller property. And that it's very likely nil.  Could that be the problem?

Comment: At your breakpoint on `[controller registerSeat:self]`, is `controller` == nil?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing here is what Xcode 4's `IBOutletCollection` is designed to solve. In your NIB, select all of your `Seat` views (these should be called `SeatView`, BTW. `Seat` should be a model class, not a view class). Drag the selected group to your `GameViewController` header and request an `IBOutletCollection`. This will wire them all as a random-ordered array. (Why they chose to make it a random-ordered array is beyond me; it's a somewhat insane construct, but it exactly matches what you're trying to do above.)

As @highlycaffeinated notes, the most likely reason for your current code failing is that you've failed to wire your `controller` and it's `nil`. When "nothing happens" in Objective-C, it's almost always because you're talking to `nil`.

Comment: Okay, yes, I'm seeing that controller's value is 0x0, which, I'm guessing is the same thing as nil right?

Okay, so...apparently there's quite a bit more I need to learn about wiring my controller.  I thought that this was how it was supposed to be done.  Am I supposed to create a new instance of the controller even though one already exists in memory?  Doesn't one get instantiated when the GameViewController awakes from nib?  I'm getting super confused about all that.  How do I make sure I'm using the same instance of my controller that already exists in memory?